# basex/rest - blog complete app

Tags: rest, basex

As part of a project, I am to implement the blog-application mentioned on this site: https://github.com/siserle/blog-example

There is absolutely no direction being provided as what I must do and I am not sure where to start. Can someone who is familiar with this type of application please let me know what steps I need to take. I am specifically supposed to implement the blog-complete section. 
The blog-complete.xqm is found the restxq folder, and it has a lot of code. I am not sure what I need to do with that code. Looking at the code, it looks like I must separate it (though i am not sure), and place some files in the webapp folder of basex and some maybe in the static folder. Anyway, I am sure anyone reading this will understand that I am completely lost. Please shed some light on what I must do.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: This question is too broad for SO, please be more specific. Maybe it is a better fit to write to the BaseX mailing list (see https://mailman.uni-konstanz.de/mailman/listinfo/basex-talk). However, it is unclear to me what you want to do as the blog-complete.xqm already exist. To _run_ the example, you can use Maven and then it is super-simple: Just run `mvn jetty:run` in the root directory, this will invoke the webapp within a Jetty server.

Comment: Thanks for responding Dirk. I am to implement that application within BaseX. I don't believe I can use Maven. What is confusing for me is how to obtain the user interface (as a form) for the user to put in the blog entry which in turn will call the xqm. I hope I make sense. This is how I was taught..that there is a form which calls the xqm file. The form resides in the static directory and the xqm file in the webapp directory. Please let me know if my concepts are all messed up.

Comment: Maven is just a build tool, you are still using BaseX. Actually, I don't really get what you are describing and yes, it sounds pretty incorrect. RestXQ enables you to use XQuery as server side processing language and thus you can generate HTML (forms, user interface, whatsoever, ...). Maybe this article in our doc clarifies the concept: https://docs.basex.org/wiki/RESTXQ

Comment: By the way, you might confuse Rest and RestXQ here. The blog example uses RestXQ exclusively, but BaseX also does have a REST interface.

Comment: Ok Dirkk, thank you, I think I will start all over and see where it takes me. Thanks for that link. I will start with that.